# How to get precision and recall using Linear svc of SVM?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have used SVM's Linear svc for training and testing the data. I'm able to get the accuracy for SVM on my dataset. But, in addition to accuracy, I need precision and recall. Can anyone suggest me how to calculate precision and recall.

MyCode:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
with open("/Users/abc/Desktop/reviews.txt") as f:
    reviews = f.read().split("\n")
with open("/Users/abc/Desktop/labels.txt") as f:
    labels = f.read().split("\n")

reviews_tokens = [review.split() for review in reviews]


onehot_enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
onehot_enc.fit(reviews_tokens)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reviews_tokens, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=None)

lsvm = LinearSVC()
lsvm.fit(onehot_enc.transform(X_train), y_train)
score = lsvm.score(onehot_enc.transform(X_test), y_test)
print("Score of SVM:" , score)
```

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predicted_y = lsvm.predict(X_test)
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_y).ravel()
precision_score = tp / (tp + fp)
recall_score = tp / (tp + fn)
```

Refer [confusion_matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) documentation for more info

Comment: Here, "train_test_split" is splitting the train data as well as the test data. Instead of that, can we give separate train and test data files to the algorithm ?

Comment: `train_test_split ` splits the given data into train & test according to the parameters you have given. We train the model (to learn the weights/coefficients) using train data & will measure the performance using test data. We do hyper parameter tuning using cross validation data

Comment: Hi @Kaslsi, Can you please look at this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250852/how-to-use-one-hot-encode-while-using-naivebayes-algorithm