# How to use One-hot Encode while using NaiveBayes algorithm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Naive Bayes algorithm for one of my requirements. In this, I have planned to use "One-hot Encode" for hyper plane. I have used the following code for running my algorithm. But, I'm not sure how to use "One-hot Encode".

Please find the below code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def load_data(filename):

    x = list()
    y = list()
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            y.append(line[1])
            x.append(line[0].split())

    return x, y

X_train, y_train = load_data('/Users/Desktop/abc/train.csv')
X_test, y_test = load_data('/Users/Desktop/abc/test.csv')

onehot_enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
onehot_enc.fit(X_train)


bnbc = BernoulliNB(binarize=None)
bnbc.fit(onehot_enc.transform(X_train), y_train)

score = bnbc.score(onehot_enc.transform(X_test), y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)
```

Can anyone please suggest me whether the above written code is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

clf = CountVectorizer()
X_train_one_hot =  clf.fit(X_train)
X_test_one_hot = clf.transform(X_test)

bnbc = BernoulliNB(binarize=None)
bnbc.fit(X_train_one_hot, y_train)

score = bnbc.score(X_test_one_hot, y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)
```

Also you can try using [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in case if you are going to use TfIdf featurization of text.

Comment: Hi Kalsi, I'm facing this error : return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: You can `lowercase` a text & not a list. This question is not at all relevant here.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Can you please look into this url and suggest me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361183/how-to-segregate-topics-using-topic-modelling-with-lda